# Can I combine these two SQL queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

`drink_orders` has many `drink_order_extras`

The first:

```
SELECT
  Sum(drink_orders.quantity * drink_orders.drink_price) AS drink_total
FROM
  drink_orders
WHERE
  drink_orders.reservation_id = 3610
```

And the second

```
SELECT
  Sum(drink_order_extras.quantity * drink_order_extras.drink_price) AS extra_total
FROM
  drink_order_extras INNER JOIN
  drink_orders ON drink_order_extras.drink_order_id = drink_orders.id
WHERE
  drink_orders.reservation_id = 3610
```

Would also be nice to get a grand total (drink_total + extra_total)

FYI, the following does **not** result in the correct sum:

```
SELECT
  Sum(drink_orders.quantity * drink_orders.drink_price) AS drink_total,
  Sum(drink_order_extras.quantity * drink_order_extras.drink_price) AS extra_total
FROM
  drink_order_extras INNER JOIN
  drink_orders ON drink_order_extras.drink_order_id = drink_orders.id
WHERE
  drink_orders.reservation_id = 3610
```

**EDIT:**

Gordon Linoff's answer works great:

```
SELECT Sum(do.quantity * do.drink_price) AS drink_total,
   Sum(extras_total) as extras_total,
   (Sum(do.quantity * do.drink_price) + COALESCE(Sum(extras_total), 0)
   ) as total
FROM drink_orders do LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT doe.drink_order_id,
         Sum(doe.quantity * doe.drink_price) as extras_total
  FROM drink_order_extras doe
  GROUP BY drink_order_id
 ) doe
 ON do.id = doe.drink_order_id
WHERE do.reservation_id = 3610;
```

Comment: maybe your third SQL is not correct because you need use an outer join? Is there a drink order without drink order extras associated?

Comment: can you edit this to show some of the data in your tables so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are summing along two different dimensions.  The `join` is causing a cartesian product -- which throws off the sums.  You can fix this by aggregating before joining:

```
SELECT Sum(do.quantity * do.drink_price) AS drink_total,
       Sum(extras_total) as extras_total,
       (Sum(do.quantity * do.drink_price) + COALESCE(Sum(extras_total), 0)
       ) as total
FROM drink_orders do LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT doe.drink_order_id,
             Sum(doe.quantity * doe.drink_price) as extras_total
      FROM drink_orders_extras doe
      GROUP BY drink_order_id
     ) doe
     ON do.id = doe.drink_order_id
WHERE do.reservation_id = 3610;
```

This first sums the extras onto the drink order.  Then it sums all the drink order information as the reservation level.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. You have a few typos. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(total) from (
SELECT
  Sum(drink_orders.quantity * drink_orders.drink_price) AS total
FROM
  drink_orders
WHERE
  drink_orders.reservation_id = 3610

UNION

SELECT
  Sum(drink_order_extras.quantity * drink_order_extras.drink_price) AS total
FROM
  drink_order_extras INNER JOIN
  drink_orders ON drink_order_extras.drink_order_id = drink_orders.id
WHERE
  drink_orders.reservation_id = 3610
) t
```